# fit html based on user screen size using webView in MAUI

Tags: webview, maui

In my MAUI application I'm using webview to display my existing static html pages. But it is giving me scrollbars horizontally and vertically. I want my html page to adjust itself based on screen-size of device.

I tried to set MaximumHeightRequest & MaximumWidthRequest but it didn't worked for me. I want to have a dynamic solution for this problem.

Comment: please give some efforts, show your code you have tried,

Comment: I can't repeat your question. Could you share with us your code for further investigation on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/8241. Look for @MobileDev327 comments

```
<ContentPage .....>
<ScrollView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Label Text="By default, a Grid contains one row and one column" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid Padding="0,30,0,0">
            <WebView x:Name="jsExampleWebView" Source="Map.html"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollView>
```

Windows

[image]

Android Emulator

> [image: Android Emulator]